# How to fade bottom edge of a scrollable TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I have a scrollable textview that I want to fade the bottom edge. I tried:

```
android:requiredFadingEdge="vertical"
```

but that only fades the top. How do I fade the bottom instead of the top?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fading at the bottom of a scrollable list on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535280/fading-at-the-bottom-of-a-scrollable-list-on-android)

Comment: That question doesn't answer my problem

Comment: Actually, I've already asked this question. But no one can answer it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910548/fading-bottom-of-scrollable-textview

Comment: I found a solution by extending TextView and overriding onDraw with a LinearGradient, similar to what is done here: https://github.com/maheswaranapk/Android-Fade-EditText-View/blob/master/fade-edit-text/src/main/java/com/fadeedittext/FadeEditText.java

Answer (score 5):

If your scrollable `TextView` happens to be implemented by wrapping it in a `ScrollView`, then quite simply add `android:requiresFadingEdge` and `android:fadingEdgeLength` for the `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/spacing_small">    

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</ScrollView>
```